# Image not Populating - Webpack, HTML & JS

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm currently trying to use webpack to create JS modules that turn JS code into HTML elements. So far it is going well, but I've run into an issue with an image not populating on my webpage. Here is the code:

```
function pageLoad () {

    const content = document.querySelector('#content');
    const home = document.createElement('div');
    home.classList.add('home');

    const pizzaImg = document.createElement('img');
    pizzaImg.src = "pics/pizza-logo.jpeg"; 

    home.appendChild(pizzaImg);
    console.log('pizza');
    return home;
}

export { pageLoad };
```

I've tried using .img but that was throwing an error which I have NOT been getting since switch to .src. I've also used a few console logs to make sure that the function was importing into my main.js file properly. The path for the image is correct relative to the HTML file so I'm really at a loss here.

For reference, my HTML code only has one div (id="content").

Edit: I figured this out. After some reconfiguration and a few more googles I found a few commands that helped me get there.

In case someone has a similar issue in the future use 'npm run build' in the terminal.

Comment: What is the rendered HTML? Is the Network tab showing the image has been found, or is it throwing  404 not found error?

Comment: @JonP - No 404 error, I see the image in the Network tab but it isnt populating on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You add the image do the `div` you create but you never appear to add that `div` to anything

```
function pageLoad () {

    const content = document.querySelector('#content');
    const home = document.createElement('div');
    home.classList.add('home');

    //actually add the home to something
    content.appendChild(home);

    const pizzaImg = document.createElement('img');
    pizzaImg.src = "pics/pizza-logo.jpeg"; 

    home.appendChild(pizzaImg);
    console.log('pizza');
    return home;
}

export { pageLoad };
```